# how to use Public API access keys for iOS app for google drive in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, xcode6

I am using my google drive a/c to allow end users to upload/download files. I don't want to ask them for credentials while using my app. But I am neither able to find a way to by pass this process, nor able to find a way for using Public API access API keys for iOS app.

Please provide some demo code if any one have.

Answer (score -1):

You can only use public access API keys when the information you are trying to retrieve does not require any user data. This does not apply in the case of Google Drive since mostly everything you can do is associated with a user, which means you will have to [authorize your requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/auth) with user credentials. It sounds like your use case involves all the users using your own singular account, which I find a little strange. This will depend on your use case, but you may want to look into [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), as that is one way to bypass the need for end users to give credentials.